# unique values from XML to combobox

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox

i have some big size xml file (>500mb) like the one bellow.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ChangeRequests Count="" ID="" Update="">
    <Requests>
        <Request Type="Insert" Method="Customer">
            <Country>xXx</Country>
            <Window>10</Window>
            <Door>11</Door>
            <Id>88747</Id>
            <Name>Lore Ipsum</Name>
            <FirstName />
            <OwnerFirstName />
            <OwnerName />
            <OwnerBirthday />
            <CompanyName1 />
            <CompanyName1 />
        </Request>
            <Request Type="Insert" Method="Customer">
            <Country>xXx</Country>
            <Window>10</Window>
            <Door>11</Door>
            <Id>444544</Id>
            <Name>Lazy Dog</Name>
            <FirstName />
            <OwnerFirstName />
            <OwnerName />
            <OwnerBirthday />
            <CompanyName1 />
            <CompanyName1 />
        </Request>
            <Request Type="Insert" Method="Customer">
            <Country>xXx</Country>
            <Window>10</Window>
            <Door>11</Door>
            <Id>444544</Id>
            <Name>Lazy Dog</Name>
            <FirstName />
            <OwnerFirstName />
            <OwnerName />
            <OwnerBirthday />
            <CompanyName1 />
            <CompanyName1 />
            </Request>
    </Requests>
</ChangeRequests>
```

i would like to read the first Request node and add to a combobox all of his childs without having to read other part of the xml.
the code that i came up with is the one below but it goes through all of them and it will add to combo box alot of duplicate values.

```
  Dim xml_doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlReader As New XmlTextReader(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim arr As New ArrayList
    xmlReader.MoveToContent()
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Request")
    While xmlReader.Read()
        Select Case xmlReader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element
                ComboBox1.Items.Add("<" + xmlReader.Name & ">")
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to read the children of the first `Request` element, you could check for the end of the `Request` element and exit the loop:

```vb
While xmlReader.Read()
    If xmlReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.EndElement AndAlso xmlReader.Name = "Request" Then
        Exit While
    End If
    Select Case xmlReader.NodeType
        ' ...
```

That would still leave you with duplicates for any child elements that are repeated, e.g. `<CompanyName1>`... but maybe that's OK.  If you also want to deduplicate those, LINQ's [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method could help out there:

```vb
Dim xmlReader As New XmlTextReader(TextBox1.Text)
xmlReader.MoveToContent()
xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Request")
' Collect the names in a List
Dim elementNames As New List(Of String)()
While xmlReader.Read()
    Select Case xmlReader.NodeType
        Case XmlNodeType.Element
            elementNames.Add("<" + xmlReader.Name & ">")
            Exit Select
    End Select
End While
' Add distinct values to the ComboBox
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(elementNames.Distinct().ToArray())
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you a 1000 times for this!!